# handler: xyz.lambda_handler is a text and i want xyz.lambda_handler as output using sh script

Tags: shell, lambda, scripting

i have "handler: xyz.lambda_handler" text in one file and i want "xyz.lambda_handler" i.e text present next to "handler:" as output using shell script, how can i do this.

I have tried

```
awk -F '${handler}' '{print $1}' filename | awk '{print $2}

grep handler filename
```

command but not getting correct output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in qtn.
I combined two commands and i got my answer

```
 grep Handler: filename | awk -F '${handler}' '{print $1}' | awk '{print $2}'
```

grep givepattern givefilename | awk -F '${givepattern}' '{print $1}' | awk '{print $2}'

Answer (score 0):

It's `grep`, not `greap`. To print  only  the  matched  parts of a matching line, use option `-o`.

```
grep -o xyz.lambda_handler filename
```

Comment: I have edited my qtn. I want string present next to "handler:" which is dynamic.